# Programming language C

Tags: c, arrays

Can a function be used to copy elements from one array and save it into another array without returning the array to main.Because once we come out of a function all the variables local to it are lost.e.g

```
 void copy(char to[],char from[])
 {
     int i;
     while((to[i]=from[i])!='\0')
     ++i;
 }
```

How does this code work?Because after copying elements from to array to from array.After the function is executed all the variables must be lost and nothing
must be saved in from array after function is executed.Please clarify my doubt.

Comment: Ever heard of pointers?

Comment: He is new, be more friendly.

Comment: You need to initialize `i` to `0` to fix this.  Remember, `i` is initially undefined and could have any value.

Answer (score 2):

The arrays are passed by pointers (the way references are used in C). So when the data is modified in the body of the function, the calling function can access the modified data.

> After the function is executed all the variables must be lost and
>   nothing must be saved in from array after function is executed.

True, objects that have liftetimes within the lifetime of the function will be lost when the function exists. However the function's lifetime has no effect on objects that have existed before it or after it.

Comment: the main problem i am having is to understand whether the elements copied from to array will exist in the from array or not after the lifetime of the function is completed

Answer (score 1):

> After the function is executed all the variables must be lost and nothing must be saved in from array after function is executed.

Not exactly.

Generally C uses call-by-value, which means the function deals with copies of the parameters and so cannot modify them.

In order to modify the variable directly, you need to pass the address of the variable (ie the pointer to it), the function then access the variable via the pointer and can modify it directly.

That's also the case when you pass an array to a function, the value passed the the function is the location/address of the first element of the array. The function itself can then access and alter any element of the array.

In short, it's totally OK for your function `copy` to modify array `to`. And usually you should make `from` as `const` because you are not changing it inside the function. So the prototype should look like this:

`void copy(char to[], const char from[]);`

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
 void copy(char to[],char from[])
```

doesn't actually take two arrays by value. Instead, the `[]` decays to a pointer, what you've actually written is:

```
 void copy(char* to, char* from)
```

This is because of [array-pointer-equivalence](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html). The language couldn't tell how big the arrays its going to need to copy would be when it compiled the function, since it could be different each time.

Thus only the pointers, `to` and `from`, are local, the data they point to is the same data that was pointed to in `main`.

Answer (score 0):

While local variables are lost at function end (scope-close), this only applies to `to` and `from` themselves -- NOT what they might point to.

BTW, your code is broken, try this instead:

```
 void copy ( char * to, char * from ) {
     while ((*to = *from) != '\0') {to++; from++;}
 }
```

Both this version and yours blindly assumes that `to` is long enough to hold the result.  This is potentially dangerous code.